# JS/CSS : transition not occurring unless within a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css

If I make a loop to dynamically add elements that do a transition on the `transform` , why does this example not work:

```
function changeSize() {
   for (let x = 0; x < 99; x++) {
      let el = document.createElement('div');
      el.style.translate = 'transformX(0px)';

      el.style.translate = 'transformX(150px)';
      el.style.transition = 'all 2s ease';
      
      let body = document.body;
      body.appendChild(el);
   }
}
```

but this does work as long as I add even a really small timeout:

```
function changeSize() {
   for (let x = 0; x < 99; x++) {
      let el = document.createElement('div');
      el.style.translate = 'transformX(0px)';

      // now it will transition 
      setTimeout(() => {
         el.style.translate = 'transformX(150px)';
         el.style.transition = 'all 2s ease';
      }, 50)

      let body = document.body;
      body.appendChild(el);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set transform and then reset it within the same thread, it just changes the value and takes on the later value. The setTimeout brings everything to a different thread on the browser level (not the javascript level, because js is single-threaded), causing the animation to occur when the value is changed. However, javascript like this is often unpredictable in different browsers - rather, use a css to make such transitions.

```js
function changeSize() {
  for (let x = 0; x < 99; x++) {
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = "hi"
    el.style.transition = "all 2s ease";
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.classList.add("transition");
    }, 1)  /*Brings everything to a different thread.
When the browser sees this, it's like - oh look, a setTimeout, I need to move this to a time thread,
so when the time completes I can execute the function! So it does that.
Since the time is very little, it completes within a short amount of time.
The browser sees this, and realizes that it needs to execute the function - so it removes it from it's
execution stack and executes it.
When executing, it sees that the thread is asking for a classList change for the element el.
So, it changes the class, triggering any css with it (in this case the transform css).
Since the element has a transition, it appropriately transitions during the translation.
*/
    document.body.appendChild(el);
  }
}
changeSize()
```

```css
.transition {
  transform: translate(100px, 0);
}
```

Note the value 1 for the setTimeout, because some browsers don't wait for the value 0 (as in move it to a separate stack).

Now, you might be wondering, why is this 'unpredictable'? Well, this is because with such a short timeout period, it can execute along with other code in the main thread. If you have code in the main thread that changes the element's css, then the browser will have a clash, and will do different things depending on which one gets executed first. However, if you use a class and then change the element's style itself later on, the style will override the class since it is applied to the element directly rather than through the means of a class.

Comment: thanks.  In your code, why does adding a line before the setTimeout to give it a starting point not work, like : `el.style.transform = translate(0px, 0px)` and then in the setTimeout below it, add the class that gives it a different translate.

Comment: That's because when you do that, the el element itself gets styled, which overrides the class. This is the exact thing that prevents css issues in later code by allowing later code to override it, and in this case, that's what it does :).

Comment: _facepalms self_ didn't notice that, thank you!!

Comment: This is a bandaid, but it's not very robust. Because CSS isn't applied immediatly. Even timeout intervals of 10 aren't guaranteed to apply on the next CSS cycle and so the transition won't occur. Easiest to notice on slower devices.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer (`setTimeout`) doesn't work on slower devices/browsers where the browser can delay applying the class change for arbitrarily long duration. Even larger thresholds like 10 or 100ms aren't guaranteed to work.

Luckily, an equally simple approach exists: query `el.offsetHeight` which won't complete until the latest pending CSS reflow is done; i.e. the pending CSS changes are applied.

```js
function changeSize() {
  for (let x = 0; x < 99; x++) {
    let el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = "hi"
    el.style.transition = "all 2s ease";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.offsetHeight;
    el.classList.add("transition");
  }
}
changeSize()
```

```css
.transition {
  transform: translate(100px, 0);
}
```